# Xaml not behaving correctly in position

Tags: xamarin.forms

For some reason my button is not showing I want the bottom to be at the bottom and green but its not. Also is their any kind of editor for grids and placements of controls would make this easier.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="WellbeingNinja.Views.RunningPage">
<ContentPage.Content>

    <Grid Padding="30,40,40,10">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>                
            <RowDefinition Height="200" />
            <RowDefinition Height="200" />
            <RowDefinition Height="200" />
            <RowDefinition Height="200" />
            <RowDefinition Height="200" />
             <RowDefinition Height="200" />
            <RowDefinition Height="200" />
             <RowDefinition Height="200" />

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"> 
            <Label x:Name="lblduration" Text="Duration"></Label>

        </StackLayout>
        <Frame Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" x:Name="frameTotalSpeed"  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"   CornerRadius="2" >
            <StackLayout>
                <Label x:Name="lblSpeedText" Text="Speed(miles)"></Label>
                <Label x:Name="lblSpeed" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="0.00" FontSize="Large" ></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame Grid.Column="1" x:Name="frameTotaldistance" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"   CornerRadius="2" >
            <StackLayout>

                <Label x:Name="lblDistance" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="0.00" FontSize="Large" ></Label>
                <Label x:Name="lbldistanceText" Text="Dist" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame Grid.Column="0" x:Name="frmTotalMilesLeft"  Grid.Row="1"   VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">

            <StackLayout>

                <Label x:Name="lblDistanceLeft" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="0.00" FontSize="Large" ></Label>
                <Label x:Name="lblavgPace" Text="Avg Pace (Min/Mil)"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>

        <Frame Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="frmTotalCarolesBurned" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">

            <StackLayout>

                <Label x:Name="lblTotalCalories" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="0.00" FontSize="Large" ></Label>
                    <Label x:Name="lblTotalCaloriesBurned" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Calories Burned"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>

          <Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" Text="Start Workout"></Button>
    </Grid>


</ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

Comment: if you rows are all height 200 then row 3 is probably off the bottom of the screen

Comment: @jason what would i be better doing then as the rows im trying to mimc a popular running app but  xaml can be a hard to say the least.

Comment: Assigning a fixed size to every row will never work because your UI will not be able to adapt to different devices.  I have no idea what "a popular running app" is or looks like so I can't help you with that.  Generally with a grid you assign * sizes to rows and columns so they can adapt to different devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you give each row with a fix height 200, then the Y position of row 3 is start from 600 and it may larger than the height of the screen. You add the Button at row 3 and it is out of the bounds of the screen. Then you won't see it in the screen.

Use a Auto would be better, it will automatically sizes to fit content in the row or column. You can also set the ColumnSpacing and RowSpacing to add some space between row and columnspace:

```
    <Grid Padding="30,40,40,10" ColumnSpacing="30" RowSpacing="70">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Read the document about [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) to get more information and you can use [StackLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout) to achieve the UI too.